# How works a deviceturn in Android

Tags: android

I would like to know how works a turn of Android device (from the point of view of the OS). I'm interested in this action, because my Android program can not save and RIGHT restore its state after any turn of device (I use it with OnSave... and OnRestore... methods), I've learned almost all tutorials, but in spite of that, I can't find the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A very detailed information on this matter is located in Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

You most likely need this section: 
**Retaining an Object During a Configuration Change**